# Conversion from Minutes To Hours:Minutes:Seconds

Tags: c#, minute

I want to convert `Minutes` as "Hours:Minutes:Seconds".

How can this achieved using c#.

I have tried this

```
driveHours = (totalHours.balanceDriveMinutes / 60).ToString("00") + " Hrs. "
 + (totalHours.balanceDriveMinutes % 60 ).ToString("00") + " Min." + 
(totalHours.balanceDriveMinutes /3600).ToString("00") + " Sec.";
```

But it doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: Do you need this specific output format or is the default of `hh:mm:ss` good enough?

Comment: What type is totalHours?

Comment: How do you expect to derive seconds when all you have coming in is minutes? What's the data type for `balanceDriveMinutes`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
driveHours = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(totalHours.balanceDriveMinutes).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```